# Automating Interaction with Dapp via code

Tags: phantom, dapp

I have multiple wallets with airdrop claims and I was wondering if theres a way to code this up instead of loading 100+ wallets into phantom and manually collecting one by one.

Is there a way to use selenium or some otherways to claim it instead ?

Thanks

Comment: I have tried the solution above but i keep on getting Invalid merkle proof, does it means i'm not eligible or?
I didn't add any proof..
any help? *spaghetti if you see this, please reply, i need your help

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use Selenium for this, because if your key is not loaded in a wallet extension, i don't know how selenium can access it ? (i don't even know if selenium can access browser extensions ?)

the only way to do it if you don't want to use a wallet extension would be to code the transaction by yourself and sign it with a keypair file. But that would imply that you know how to build this transaction (arguments, accounts...) it may be not too complicated, but you have to find a successfull transaction in order to try to understand how it's built

Comment: You can use extensions in Selenium (i guess it would technically be chrome/edge/firefox webdriver) you just need to unpack them first if i recall. I just used solflare web wallet though and had selenium import each from a list into solflare web wallet, then interacted using its popup etc

Answer (score 1):

Yea you can definitely use selenium, I've done it a handful of times. You can use solflare's web wallet, or you can load extensions with some capabilities flags.

The easiest thing to do is just find a claim transaction on solscan, and build a transaction instruction w/ the same keys and data you find. Just copy paste the instruction data(click the view in hex button on solscan) and pass it into a transaction w/ the program ID also found on solscan:

const instructionData = Buffer.from("e8ji793nsy6", "hex")

accountMetas = [
{pubkey: account1, isSigner: true, isWritable: true},
{pubkey: account2, isSigner: false, isWritable: true}]

const programId = new PublicKey(" ")

const instruction = new TransactionInstruction({accountMetas, instructionData, programId})
const tx = new Transaction().add(instruction)
const submit = await connection.sendTransaction(tx, [signer])

literally just copy the exact same order for the accounts as you find on solscan. the first account of the instruction on solscan goes in the first of the account metas, repeat this for every account including the system programs, clock, rent, everything, along with their signer/writable tags.

compare two claim txs to find which accounts change between two different claim txs. (normally for a very basic program only the claiming wallet, the claiming wallets token account/s and the claiming wallets airdrop data account would change, and every other account would remain constant between two given claiming wallets)

which airdrop? i may have already done the above for it and i can help you further

Comment: Hi the airdrop is for the Jupiter, but how do we add the individual wallets to phantom though ?

Comment: much easier to just get the endpoint from devtools when you connect your wallet to their check page, then make a loop replacing the wallet string in the endpoint + fetch. make sure to lowercase your wallet addr first, and i want to say you can expect an error 403 unless you have allocation, it will break the loop but just use a try catch to keep it going

Comment: I see, thanks for the help ! I was actually trying to claim it for the Jupiter airdrop. Do you have any advice on how to do so (ie: if you have done it already ?)